# CRAN package with dependencies from Bioconductor fails on MAC when installing

Tags: r, cran, bioconductor

I've build a package & submitted to CRAN.
The package rKOMICS has been accepted and can be installed on Windows.
On Mac however, an error occurs:

`checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Package required but not available: ‘ComplexHeatmap’

See section ‘The DESCRIPTION file’ in the ‘Writing R Extensions’
manual.`

ComplexHeatmap is a package from Bioconductor. I've put 'biocViews:' in the DESCRIPTION file but it doesn't seem to work.
If I put 'Remotes: bioc::3.13/ComplexHeatmap' in the DESCRIPTION file I receive following error message when submitting: "Unknown, possibly misspelled, fields in DESCRIPTION: 'Remotes'"

Anyone an idea?

Thanks